# React empty JSX tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, datatables, jsx

I'm placing data coming from a database in JSX tables but for some reason I'm getting a lot of empty table cells, picture below

[image]

When I fill the table with data, these empty table cells still stand there for no reason.

I tried deleting the `PlayerPitching()` call from `<tbody>{this.PlayerPitching()}</tbody>` but then the empty table cells dissappear totally.

Picture below of when the `PlayerPitching()` is not being called:

[image]

Here's the file code:

```js
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    
        const Nov11001vistBat = (props) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{props.batter.Batter}</td>
            <td>{props.batter.AB}</td>
            <td>{props.batter.R}</td>
            <td>{props.batter.H}</td>
            <td>{props.batter.RBI}</td>
          </tr>
        );
        
        const Nov11001vistPit = (props) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{props.pitcher.Pitcher}</td>
            <td>{props.pitcher.IP}</td>
            <td>{props.pitcher.P_H}</td>
            <td>{props.pitcher.P_R}</td>
            <td>{props.pitcher.ER}</td>
          </tr>
        );
        
        
        export default class Nov11001vist extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        
            this.state = { batters: [], pitchers: [] };
          }
        
          componentDidMount() {
            axios
              .get("http://localhost:5000/001nov11vist/")
              .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ batters: response.data, pitchers: response.data });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        
          PlayerBatting() {
            return this.state.batters.map((currentBatter) => {
              return <Nov11001vistBat batter={currentBatter} key={currentBatter._id} />;
            });
          }
        
          PlayerPitching() {
            return this.state.pitchers.map((currentPitcher) => {
              return <Nov11001vistPit pitcher={currentPitcher} key={currentPitcher._id} />;
            });
          }
        
          render() {
            return (
              <div className="">
                <style type="text/css">
                  {`
                          th {
                            background-color: #DC3545;
                            color: #F9DEE0;
                        }
                        .table th,
                        .table td{
                          margin: 0;
                          padding: 0.08rem;
                          font-size: 0.8rem;
                          border: 0.6px solid rgba(40,40,40,0.3);
                          text-align: center;
                        }
                        .table td {
                          color: black;
                        }
                        .table th {
                          color: white;
                        }
                       `}
                </style>
                <br />
                <h2 className="text-light text-center">Team Blue</h2>
        
                <br />
        
                <br />
                <div
                  className="card mx-auto"
                  style={{
                    maxWidth: "1000px",
                    height: "auto",
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    paddingTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                    paddingRight: "10px",
                    paddingLeft: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <h4 className="text-dark text-center mt-2">
                    Batting Statistics <hr />
                  </h4>
                  <div className="table-responsive-xl">
                    <table className="table table-striped mx-auto">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Team Navy</th>
                          <th scope="col">AB</th>
                          <th scope="col">R</th>
                          <th scope="col">H</th>
                          <th scope="col">RBI</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>{this.PlayerBatting()}</tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div className="table-responsive-xl">
                    <table className="table table-striped mx-auto">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Team Gray</th>
                          <th scope="col">IP</th>
                          <th scope="col">H</th>
                          <th scope="col">R</th>
                          <th scope="col">ER</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>{this.PlayerPitching()}</tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
        
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: coz you set same data for batters & pitchers `this.setState({ batters: response.data, pitchers: response.data });` try to console.log(response.data), to understand whats your backend return in the response.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the table below is always rendered is because it is being written in JSX. For it to be removed you'd have to do:

```
<div className="">
            <style type="text/css">
              {`
                      th {
                        background-color: #DC3545;
                        color: #F9DEE0;
                    }
                    .table th,
                    .table td{
                      margin: 0;
                      padding: 0.08rem;
                      font-size: 0.8rem;
                      border: 0.6px solid rgba(40,40,40,0.3);
                      text-align: center;
                    }
                    .table td {
                      color: black;
                    }
                    .table th {
                      color: white;
                    }
                   `}
            </style>
            <br />
            <h2 className="text-light text-center">Team Blue</h2>
    
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div
              className="card mx-auto"
              style={{
                maxWidth: "1000px",
                height: "auto",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                paddingTop: "10px",
                paddingBottom: "10px",
                paddingRight: "10px",
                paddingLeft: "10px",
              }}
            >
              <h4 className="text-dark text-center mt-2">
                Batting Statistics <hr />
              </h4>
              <div className="table-responsive-xl">
                <table className="table table-striped mx-auto">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Team Navy</th>
                      <th scope="col">AB</th>
                      <th scope="col">R</th>
                      <th scope="col">H</th>
                      <th scope="col">RBI</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{this.PlayerBatting()}</tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <br />
            <br />
          </div>
```

How these tables work is that they match the table columns to the object that is passed through. The reason the batting tables work is that the columns names match that of the object perfectly - `[ AB, R, H, RBI ]`. However, for the pitchers, the table columns are  `[ IP, H, R, ER ]` but your pitcher object has fields of `[ IP, P_H, P_R, ER ]`. Thus, the table is able to find that you have a number of rows, but it is unable to serialize that information. To fix this, you simply have to do:

```
const Nov11001vistPit = (props) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{props.pitcher.Pitcher}</td>
        <td>{props.pitcher.IP}</td>
        <td>{props.pitcher.H}</td>
        <td>{props.pitcher.R}</td>
        <td>{props.pitcher.ER}</td>
      </tr>
    );
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help, It happens that the problem was on the backend -- There were 10 responses on the table side that were, at the same time taking up space on the bottom table. In the same manner, if I added items to the bottom table, empty spaces would appear on the top table; this was because I was using the same DB model/collection for different tables in the same React Component (I'm using MongoDB for the DB). The solution was using a different model/collection for each table. I have no idea why this happens though.